# derived querying a nullable @OneToOne relationship with JPA and Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I have a Entity1 and Entity2

```
@Entity
class Entity1 {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "entity_id")
   private Long entityId;

   @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id")    
   private Entity2 entity2;
   ...
}
```

How can I derived query all Entity1 objects that has a null entity2?
IntelliJ Idea tell that i can use smth like that:

```
List<Entity1> findAllByEntity2IsNull()
```

But that doesn't work and return empty list always

I tried to use an opposite variant:

```
List<Entity1> findAllByEntity2IsNotNull()
```

But that variant return all entries that have null and not null values

Answer (score 0):

I guess, find**All**ByEntity2IsNull confuses Spring Data, so try using method with name

```
List<Entity1> findByEntity2IsNull()
```

Comment: I tried that variant and it also doesn't work
i used findByEntity2IsNull() - it returns empty list although i have entities1 with null entity2
Also i tried use to findByEntity2IsNotNull() and in that case i get again all entries with null and not null